# How to make tabbed panel browser of many opened browsers in a single window

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-chrome

If we have a tab window in Firefox/Chrome we make maximize each tab window by pulling it out.

Would it be possible to revert it back?(Drag the opened browser window & drop on the other window to make it as a tabbed panel) using JS/jQ in Firefox/Google Chrome?

Comment: @Chris Marasti-Georg: OK. Generally in browser we have drag & drop functions for many things. So, would it be possible to use the  drag & drop function to drop a window on another window then it makes an automatic tab window.

Comment: Do you mean a browser window, or a piece of HTML that is styled to look/act like a window, which many UI frameworks have?  You can do whatever you want with UI windows withing a browser window.  If you pop open a new window, you can pass messages back and forth between those 2 windows with javascript.  I doubt a browser would let you drag a UI window from one browser window to another.

Comment: @Chris Marasti-Georg: would it possible with the browser window?

Comment: No, I don't believe that is possible with javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Browsers don't really let you control the chrome, other than occasionally popping open a new window, or closing one that you opened.

There are some older, convtroversial methods on the `window` object to allow [resizing and moving](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/advwin.shtml), but they don't work in the latest version of Chrome (thankfully).